# django-cacheops doesn't work with South

Tags: python, django, caching, django-south

Just installed django-cacheops. However, when I try to run `python manage.py migrate` or `python manage.py syncdb`, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/stanleytang/Desktop/DoorDash/Development/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/stanleytang/Desktop/DoorDash/Development/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/stanleytang/Desktop/DoorDash/Development/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Users/stanleytang/Desktop/DoorDash/Development/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 75, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Users/stanleytang/Desktop/DoorDash/Development/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/stanleytang/Desktop/DoorDash/Development/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/Users/stanleytang/Desktop/DoorDash/Development/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 25, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError cacheops: cannot import name app_directories
```

I'm on django 1.6 and using django-cacheops 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

This turned to be a circular import in templates, not related to cacheops. Here is [the issue](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops/issues/108).

To take home: circular imports provide lousy error messages in Python :)